# List Meteor methods registered with Meteor.methods()?

Tags: meteor

Wondering if there was a way to get a list of the current Meteor.methods that have been registered.

for example if a post method is registered like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
  post: function() {
    //code
  }
});
```

Is there a way to access a list of these methods? Ideally it would be via a method but if it was stored in an accessible variable like Meteor.__methods that would work as well.

I've combed through the documentation and the Meteor global in the browser but did no find anything useful. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the client you can do:

```
Meteor.connection._methodHandlers
```

It gives you a dictionary of function names to functions.

Comment: It doesn't list methods.

Comment: @avalanche1 It does for me. Maybe your methods aren't actually getting registered or something?

Comment: This will only list methods that have a client stub. If the method is _only_ registered on the server it won't appear here, you'll need to run it on the server (see Kelly Copley's answer)

Answer (score 17):

After Digging more on the Server side of meteor, it appears that the methods are stored in an array `Meteor.default_server.method_handlers` which is accessible on the server but not on the client.

Only way to expose it client side seems to be registering a method server side and then returning a list of the keys.

Comment: It's not exposed to the client side because that could open a potential security flaw

Comment: I do have secure/server defined methods and `Meteor.default_server.method_handlers` doesn't contain my methods when running in test mode run by `meteortesting:mocha` but they do exist in dev mode! Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out that I had to import the file containing my methods logic into the test for it to be loaded! Is this behavior intended?